# Evicting read-only memory mapped pages from memory?

Tags: windows, memory-management, io

I have some huge binary files which I'm currently reading using memory mapping on Windows. Everything works fine, but problems start when the file size is larger than memory. For instance, on a 24 GiB memory machine, I map a 64 GiB file and then I'm doing more or less streaming reads through it (not totally streaming, but ok'ish.) Nevertheless, the process winds up using all memory at some point.

I'm touching each byte in the file exactly once, so it should be enough to keep let's say 4-5 GiB around for optimal performance. Is there a way to force Windows (7) to discard pages? FlushViewOfFile discards *dirty* pages only, but in my use case, I'm only reading from the file. I've already set the NO_BUFFER flag, but I'd like to be able to reduce the page priority somehow so they get evicted more quickly. Right now, once the memory is full, the app comes to a grinding halt as Windows pages out everything.

[Edit] It's a 64-bit application on a 64-bit windows.

Comment: `FlushViewOfFile` syncs pages with the disk, the documentation doesn't suggest that it would discard any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't map it all as a single view.  Call `CreateFileMapping` once, then call `MapViewOfFile` and `UnmapViewOfFile` as you need segments of the file.  `UnmapViewOfFile` should cause the pages to be discarded.

You can of course have several views from the same file mapping at once, they can be overlapping or non-overlapping, and overlapping views will be coherent (even across different file mappings and different processes).

Comment: Yup, that's as good as it gets if you don't want to use AWE. Unluckily there is no madvise under Windows.

Comment: Unmap won't necessarily discard. The kernel might keep them around just in case someone else opens the file.

Comment: @bmargulies: True, but it should reduce the page priority dramatically to have no references to it.

Comment: I agree that one would certainly hope so.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to VirtualUnlock the pages you know you won't be using for a while. If the pages are not currently locked, VirtualUnlock will remove them from the working set and place them on the standby list, just as if you unmapped them.